# Fullpage.js how to dynamize transitions

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, fullpage.js, animate.css

I need my code works as follows:
When I scroll from one section to another independent scroll up or down, include the `.compass-areas-centered` and `.bg-areas` classses in the current section.

HTML

this code below generate sections dynamic

```
<?php foreach ( $items as $k => $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<div class="section">

    <div class="large-12 columns compass-areas">

        <img src="<?php echo $secaoImgUrl[0]; ?>" class="bg-areas" />

        <div class="compass-areas-centered">
            <!-- .compass-areas-centered -->
        </div>

    </div>

</div><!-- .section -->

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

JS

```
 onLeave: function( index, nextIndex, direction ){

        var leavingSection = $(this);

        // AFTER LEAVE HOME APPLY FX IN COMPASS
        if( index == 1 && nextIndex == 2 ){
            $( '.compass-areas-centered' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInDown' );
            $( '.bg-areas' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInUp' );
        }

        if( index == 2 && nextIndex == 3 ){
            $( '.compass-areas-centered' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInDown' );
            $( '.bg-areas' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInUp' );
        }

        if( index == 3 && nextIndex == 4 ){
            $( '.compass-areas-centered' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInDown' );
            $( '.bg-areas' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInUp' );
        }

        if( index == 4 && nextIndex == 5 ){
            $( '.compass-areas-centered' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInDown' );
            $( '.bg-areas' ).toggleClass( 'animated fadeInUp' );
        }

    }
```

JS FIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/y3barsq6/
GIF
sometimes i need back to effects work
http://giphy.com/gifs/l3V0Bhrg1PJ33HMBi

Comment: dynamize transitions? What's that. And what's the problem with your current code? Can you add a reproduction on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: @Alvaro here https://jsfiddle.net/y3barsq6/ like the effect to be added and removed soon after to face section.

Comment: I still not understanding what is your problem. What's wrong with your current code? Explain it better and update the question please.

Comment: @Alvaro every time I scroll down to the bottom `.compass-areas-centered` classes and `.bg-areas` must receive the added effects with `toggleclass` and remove them soon then for every time I'm in the current section the effect function.

Comment: @Alvaro gif example, sometimes i need back to effects work http://giphy.com/gifs/l3V0Bhrg1PJ33HMBi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using animate.css library.

Just read [in the docs](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/#usage) the recommended approach to remove the classes once the animation is finished:

```
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});
```

Then use:

```
$('#yourElement').animateCss('bounce');
```